# swapping int with string using getchar() and putchar()

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, replace

For my homework I have to swap and int with a character. For example if the user types in 1 the output should be "one".  this should work from zero to 5.

My Idea would be to implement a char array that looks like this.

```
*string[] = { "zero\0", ....., "five\0"}
```

Then I would implement it in a code like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    int c; 
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        putchar(c);
    }

    return 0; 
}
```

So since I am only allowed to use putchar and getchar and no heap. 
This would be my approach: I would create a for loop that would print out the every letter until  \0 is reached.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: This approach does not seem to use string at all.

Comment: 1) string literals are already null-terminated, you shouldn't add another `\0` at the end. 2) if `i == 0`, then `string[i]` will evaluate to `"zero"` (or, in your case `"zero\0"`).

Comment: @IncreasinglyIdiotic: the way I read it, OP wants to print `one` when the user types in `1`. The string literal `"one"` already contains 4 characters, the last being `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but here are a few pointers.

I'm not sure what `*string[]` is, but because you know the size of your array ahead of time you can make a fixed size `char*` array to hold your strings like this

```
char* arr[6] = {"zero\0", "one\0", ..., "five\0"};
```

Notice the array has both a type (`char*`) and a name (`arr`).

Next you can read in the number you wish to print with

```
int c = getchar();
```

And you can use your previously defined array to get the correct string and loop over it printing it one char at a time with `putchar`

```
char* str = arr[c];
for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    putchar(str[i]);
}
putchar('\n');
```

---

And as [Groo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50267263/swapping-int-with-string-using-getchar-and-putchar/50267487?noredirect=1#comment87552507_50267263) pointed out string literals are implicitly null terminated so you son't need to include `\0` on your strings. The array can just be

```
char* arr[6] = {"zero", "one", ..., "five"};
```

And everything will still work.

Comment: thank you very much , I included an if(c==48) and changed the char* str = arr[c]; to char* str = arr[0]; and it worked

Comment: @makoto don't put ASCII value numbers in your code where characters should go, e.g. `if (c == 48)` is much more readable as `if (c == '0')`. In fact if you are taking input with `getchar()`, you can check `if ('0' <= c && c <= '9) printf ("%d is '%s'\n", c , arr[c-'0']);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin you said if(c==48) is more readable. Thats what I did.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the opposite of what I was saying, but to each his own `:)`